# What is the ontological status of gauge fields/virtual particles/electron radiation in Dirac sea model of Bohmian QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electrons, quantum-interpretations, virtual-particles, bohmian-mechanics

I have been reading about this model - it is a model without actual particle creation or annihilation, particles move deterministically according to Bohm's law, the Dirac sea is used to explain away creation/annihilation, which all gives a very neat and simple ontology. But when it comes to particle interaction, I am stuck. The model does not include bosons into its ontology, so it is very confusing to me how fermion interaction is handled. Could someone with sufficient knowledge try to explain it in simple terms?
More precisely, I am wondering what actually happens in physical space when two electrons interact, according to the aforementioned model?